# mysql insert with auto-increment column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data into a mysql table from a csv file.  I am using the infile sql command, but I am having trouble because the first column of the table is an id that is set as an auto increment field.  what do I have to set my first column value to in order to get this to work, or can I do it at all?

Thanks

Comment: I actually just ended up removing the autoincrement column, and doing a regular load data.  I then was able to add in the auto-increment column afterwords.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using an empty field or a TAB character as a first column value in a file

(see comment "Posted by Mohamed Abdulla on August 17 2005 11:14am" on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html)

Another solution:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'DATA.txt' INTO TABLE your_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '~'
(column2, column3, ... )
SET column1 = NULL
```

Comment: The `SET` clause is optional here.